# Pact Request That Depends on the Response from A Previous Request

Tags: pact

I am using the Pact framework to test some APIs from a service. I have one API that initiates some backend execution. Let's call it request A and the response returns a unique execution ID. The second API (request B) send the execution ID returned from request A to pull the execution status. How do I set up the pact test in this case? The problem is the execution ID that is generated dynamically. I know a provider can inject some provider state to the consumer. So potentially, the execution ID could be injected. But I am not sure how to make the injection from the provider side. It requires access to the response from the response A and inject the execution ID (with the provider state callback, perhaps) for the second request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have a lot of control over what is happening in your provider for Pact to work for you.

Each interaction is verified individually (and in some frameworks, in a random order), and all state should be cleared in between interactions, so you need to use provider states to set up any data that would have been created by the initial request. In regards to something like the execution IDs, you could use a different implementation of the code that generates the IDs that you only use for Pact Tests.

Comment: Thanks. I'll have to verify the two API separately. For the second API that pulls the execution status using an execution ID, I'll have to use a provider state to inject the ID to the consumer. How to generate the ID is up to my implementation. The worst case, I make a call to the first API in the provider call back, parse the returned execution ID, and inject the ID to the consumer. Just to summarize my understanding for future references.